# How to return model object to the Ajax

Tags: model-view-controller

```
 Public JSONResult savedata(details d)
 {
    Return Json (d);
 }

$.ajax({
  url: "report/savedata",
  type: "post",
  data: formdata
}).done(function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

The data is not coming from controller to ajax.i want to access id of  detail  model

Comment: 1) What do you get in the alert? 2) Are you sure controller received data?

Comment: Not getting anything Yes controller received data.done(function(data) {
  If (data.status==true) alert(data)else alert("error");
});.      It received error alert

Comment: That doesn't mean controller received data. Set a breakpoint in controller.

Comment: Controller getting data but it not passing to the Ajax

Comment: Pretty sure it's not. Try `return Json("d")` and see if `data` is the string `"d"`.

Comment: Ok but it will send string but I want object to be send

Comment: Did you even try it?

Answer (score 0):

Add an breakpoint to the controller method and see whether it gets a request. If so see whether its returning the object with data.If it is then should check the js file.